# node:internal/validators:163 throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(name, 'string', value);

Tags: javascript, error-handling, discord, discord.js, dashboard

When I do node index.js this error comes up -

```
node:internal/validators:163
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(name, 'string', value);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:393:5)
    at validateString (node:internal/validators:163:11)
    at join (node:path:1172:7)
    at Dashboard._getTheme (/home/runner/Jacoby/node_modules/discord-easy-dashboard/index.js:67:24)
    at new Dashboard (/home/runner/Jacoby/node_modules/discord-easy-dashboard/index.js:48:25)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/Jacoby/index.js:13:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

My index.js -

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { Client, Collection, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const Dashboard = require("discord-easy-dashboard");
const { token, baseUrl, port, client_secret } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

client.db = require('quick.db');

client.commands = new Collection();
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

client.dashboard = new Dashboard(client, {
    name: 'DashBot',
    description: 'A super cool bot with an online dashboard!',
    serverUrl: 'https://discord.gg/',
    baseUrl,
    port,
    secret: client_secret,
});
require('./setDashboardSettings')(client.dashboard);

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
    client.dashboard.registerCommand(command.data.name, command.data.description, `/${command.data.name} ${command.data.options.map(option => option.name).join(' ')}`);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

    if (!command) return;

    try {
        await command.execute(interaction);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return interaction.reply({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
    }
});

client.login(token);
```

That is my index.js, i'm using a discord.js package for the dashboard. I'm also working with other people and were trying to fix this problem please help me as fast as possible, and i'll help you with coding. Also I know my index.js is really bad so please don't judge.

Comment: The error states a `path` argument was expected but received undefined. The stack trace shows the error coming from `new Dashboard()` I imagine you need to provide a `path` to the options

Comment: I am making this on repl.it so

Comment: I don't see the point you're trying to make, Repl.it  does not have an affect on this